# data union with tables

Tags: sql

I have below query

```
SELECT Vehicle_ID,Total_Weight,date,bilty_No FROM harvesting
UNION
SELECT Vehicle_ID,Total_Weight,date,Bilty_No FROM Blade_Harvesting
```

Now i want to show vehicle_name instead of vehicle_ID from vehicle table..
how can i add vehicle table and show name instead of ID?

Comment: Join it to your query and select it?

Comment: Maybe edit your question... We dont know what you data tables look like. You need us to be provided with more information

Comment: I have  1 table harvesting 2nd blade harvesting i have required above columns with vehicle name instead of vehicle ID as i mention above.I want to show vehicle name which is 3rd table vehicle.. How can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here we union your tables as before, aliasing the result as "h", and join onto your vehicle table. This assumes your vehicle table has columns "id" and "vehicle_name". Note that any Vehicle_IDs not present in both the vehicle table and the harvesting table will be omitted from the results, as this is an inner join. To show all vehicles, change "inner join" to "left join". This tells the database to retain everything in your vehicle table, and return NULL values from your harvesting table where there is no corresponding harvesting data.

```
Select v.vehicle_name, h.Total_Weight, h.date, h.bilty_No
from
vehicle_table v
inner join
(
  SELECT Vehicle_ID,Total_Weight,date,bilty_No FROM harvesting
  UNION
  SELECT Vehicle_ID,Total_Weight,date,Bilty_No FROM Blade_Harvesting
) h
on h.Vehicle_ID = v.id
```

Comment: query works fine and show data very well with all vehicle names but when i add to crystal report to get report vehicle name wise  its only showing 2 vehicles but i have 48 vehicles in database..don't know why

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I am guessing that there is not harvesting data for all vehicle types? Inner joins will not return these rows as they require corresponding IDs to be in both tables. I have updated my answer text to have a left join, which will return all the vehicles, and join on the harvesting data where applicable.

Comment: its working fine on sql bro...but when i add on report to filter vehicle name wise its show only 3 vehicle as i have 48 vehicles on my database..dont know whats the problem -;(

Comment: Glad to hear the SQL is now working. I am unsure about the crystal report though as I've never used that. It might be worth editing your current question, or even creating a new one as crystal reports do not get mentioned in your text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query --

```
 SELECT Vehicle_Name
    ,Total_Weight
    ,DATE
    ,bilty_No
FROM harvesting H
INNER JOIN Vehicle V 
ON H.Vehicle_ID = V.Vehicle_ID

UNION

SELECT Vehicle_Name
    ,Total_Weight
    ,DATE
    ,Bilty_No
FROM Blade_Harvesting BH
INNER JOIN Vehicle V 
ON BH.Vehicle_ID = V.Vehicle_ID
```

Comment: query works fine and show data very well with all vehicle names but when i add to crystal report to get report vehicle name wise its only showing 2 vehicles but i have 48 vehicles in database..don't know why